# Can't mount cifs smb unless vers=1.0

Tags: smb, cifs

I am on Ubuntu 21.04 and the command I am running now is as follows

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/g /mnt/network -o user=user,vers=3,sec=ntlm --verbose
```

and the result, nomatter what combination of variables is always

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.1,unc=\\192.168.0.1\g,vers=3,sec=ntlm,user=user,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

if I change the vers parameter to `vers=1.0` the mount works perfectly without error.

As far as I can see from the man mount.cifs there is no invalid argument that I am passing in and I have been having a hell of a time finding anything regarding the error I am seeing.

I have tried tail syslogs, but the error message there is not very helpful, just saying

```
CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.0.1\g
FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
FS-Cache: O-cookie c=00000000daddcf90 [p=000000009dd1318b fl=222 nc=1 na=1]
FS-Cache: O-cookie d=0000000043e1efc3 n=0000000079106b44
FS-Cache: O-key=[8] '020001bdc0a80001'
FS-Cache: N-cookie c=0000000025a3f19f [p=000000009dd1318b fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
FS-Cache: N-cookie d=0000000043e1efc3 n=000000002879ec5a
FS-Cache: N-key=[8] '020001bdc0a80001'
CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

My ultimate goal is to run chown commands on the mounted directories contents, I was hoping maybe a different version might change the struggles I have been having with that, but I will post another question specific to that issue. In the meantime, I'd just like to be able to use the smb3 protocol

Answer (score 1):

You may need to replace `vers=3` with `vers=3.0` or `vers=3.11`.